# How to render a single post inside a section, from a function in the controller

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I'm developing a personal blog but I can't get the browser to show me what I have in a function which has yet to show me a single post, however I can manage to view a list of all the posts, I can view just 5 (latest) which appear on the main, homepage.

Now I'm going for the part where you click on the title and everything about this post should be displayed. I inspected the code on the part where I'm having the issues and the part where the foreach is isn't being rendered to the browser, maybe I'm not doing something correct on the blade part?

PostsController.php

```
    public function show(Post $slug)
    {
        $post = Post::find($slug);
        return view('posts.show', ['posts' => $post]);
    }
```

Posts/show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('showpost')

    <div>
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <h1> {{ $post->title }} </h1>
            <p> {{ $post->body }} </p>
        @endforeach
    </div>

@endsection
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
```

Just to show you how I'm referencing the template that shows just one post.

```
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <li>
                <a href="/posts/{{ $post->slug }}">
                    <h1> {{ $post->title }} </h1>
                </a>
                <p> {{ $post->slug }} </p>
            </li>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Really no need for `foreach` if you only want to show one post. `@section('showpost')`: is that the correct section name? It usually is `content`, do you `@yield('showpost')` in your `app.blade.php`?

Comment: i honestly thought naming all sections as 'content' it would interfere somehow but i guess not, i prefer it that way now, its simpler. thanks. i removed the foreach loop and it finds an undefined variable, tried changing this part ```['posts' => $post]);``` to ```['post' => $post]);``` and throws a different kind of error "Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement the Route Model Binding completely, you need to specify it in 3 places, **routes.php**, **PostsController.php** and override it on the model, **Post.php**:

1. Pass the desired target inside the get request method and place it inside the wildcard, this is next to where you specify the controller and which function to use inside of the controller.

From this: `Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');`

To this: `Route::get('/posts/{slug}', 'PostsController@show');`

2. Override the target (from id to "whatever") using the **getRouteKeyModel** function, this is just like @Yves Kipondo had provided

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Tweak the **show** function inside the **PostsController**, passing the Model's name and the target so the query is completed. All of this inside the parameter of the function. And since your'e overriding the use of the id, you no longer have to specify it inside Eloquent query to the database.

So, instead of this:

```
    public function show(Post $slug)
    {
        $post = Post::find($slug);
        return view('posts.show', ['posts' => $post]);
    }
```

Change it to this:

```
    public function show(Post $slug)
    {
        return view('posts.show', ['post' => $slug]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Post::find` is used to retrieve a model by its primary key which is in most cases named `id`. Heir in your case you are passing `$slug` as an argument, and as It's is supposed to render only a single item with a given `slug` you should use `Post::where('slug', $slug)->first()` this will only return one item and you won't have to use a `foreach` loop in the `show.blade.php` template.

Another problem is here

```
public function show(Post $slug) {
    $post = Post::find($slug);
    return view('posts.show', ['posts' => $post]);
}
```

You are using `Route Model Binding` which will automatically set the parameter `$slug` of the function `show` equal to the record in the `posts` table which has the `id` which is passed in the URL request. No need to perform `Post::find($slug)`

for example, if the request URL is `http://localhost:8000/posts/1` here the **id** is **1** so the parameter `$slug` will be populated with the record which has `id==1` unless you have **Customizing The Key** like this

Define in the `App\Models\Post::class` a method call

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

With this definition, the `post` item which will be retrieved when performing Route model biding will be based on the value of the `slug` column within a `posts` table.

You can learn more about at [Route Model Biding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: Undefined variable